# How to select a diffrent item from a list of values each time a loop repeats in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, selenium, arraylist

So basically what I am looking to do is grab a new item from a list every time i call that list. My list looks something like this

```
testemail+0@gmail.com
testemail+1@gmail.com
testemail+2@gmail.com
testemail+3@gmail.com
...
```

So I will automatically send the email to the first one and then send the keys for the body text after. I have all the open and close email window, I am just not sure how to pull the next email address I want when i start the next email.

My ideal goal for this project is to be able to store all the emails in a separate file and then take the emails from that file

so basically every time i query the variable it has the next item in the list

thanks in advance appreciate it

Comment: You will need to show us what you have tried so far and any applicable html or link to html that you are trying to interact with before we can offer much help.

Comment: to be 100% i have so little clue of where to start i understnad the basic concept that i will need a file with predetermined emails, but i have no idea how to import that and pull the next email when i send the first

Comment: Sounds like you have a couple of questions in this one that need a bit more research and attempts to really offer help.  There's plenty of information on how to read a file and pull out the data.  Another item to figure out is what you want to do with each line item read. If you want to send it to a website field then that can involve selenium or another way to interact with a brower.  We would need html to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just not sure how to pull the next email address I want when i start the next email.

```
for email_address in open('emails.txt').read().splitlines():
    send_email(email_address)
```